# Insert Into Error

Tags: ms-access

So I have a system that in which I am required to take data from an unbound text box and commit said data to a bound text box. That part works just fine, but I'm also wanting to use the insert into command to capture the information in the unbound box and commit it to a type of historical table.

```
db.Execute "Insert Into stagingtest (Me.A, Me.B, Me.C)" & _
              "Values(" & Me.txtA & ", " & Me.txtB & ", " & Me.txtC & ")"
```

That's what I have currently, but everytime I run it, I get an "Object Required" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into stagingtest (A, B, C)" & _
              "Values ('" & Me.txtA & "', '" & Me.B & "', '" & Me.C & "')"
```

and it seems to work without a hitch.

My apologies if I wasted anyone's time.

Comment: It would have been nice to acknowledge @HelloW's valuable input.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like your syntax isn't referencing actual fields.
From your SQL statment it looks like you have a field in *stagingtest* named *Me.A*.  If you replace Me.A,Me.B,Me.C with valid fields everything should work.

Comment: Er, my apologies. There is no "(Me.A, Me.B, Me.C.)" It is just (A, B, C) currently.